# X-Path/XSL Parsing Issue

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Below is input xml:

```
<MEA>
  <MEA01>PD</MEA01>
  <MEA02>
    <MEA0201>HT</MEA0201>
  </MEA02>
  <MEA03>
    <MEA0301>CMT</MEA0301>
    <MEA0302>12.300000</MEA0302>
  </MEA03>
</MEA>
```

In the below XSL-Expression I'm checking `PD` and `HT` values and based on that I have to take `MEA0302` element value.

But below expression is not giving any value.

```
<xsl:value-of select="MEA[MEA01='PD']/MEA02[MEA0201='HT']/MEA03/MEA0302"/>
```

Comment: In your example, MEA01, MEA02 and MEA03 are *siblings*, not parent, child and grandchild. The purpose of the test is not quite clear - unless there are multiple MEA elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will resolve your issue:

```
MEA[MEA01='PD' and MEA02/MEA0201='HT']/MEA03/MEA0302
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
MEA[MEA01='PD']/MEA02[MEA0201='HT']/../MEA03/MEA0302
```

Or maybe this has more sense:

```
MEA[MEA01='PD' and MEA02[MEA0201='HT']]/MEA03/MEA0302
```

The issue was basically that you were getting into `MEA02` and then trying to get the `MEA03` that was inside `MEA02` and that node didn't actually exist. So you can get into it and then come back to the parent node (first case) or just query it from the parent node (second case).